# How to initializate nextToken for first page of pagination?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, graphql-js

I using aws amplify and reactjs as front end.

```
const [nextToken, setNextToken] = useState("");

 const fetchData = async () =>{
    try{
      // console.log(listPictures);
      let varjson={}
      if(page==1){
        varjson = {limit: perPage}
      }else{
        varjson = {limit: perPage, nextToken: nextToken}
      }
      const pictureData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listPictures, varjson));
      console.log('nextToken:', pictureData.data.listPictures.nextToken);
      setNextToken(pictureData.data.listPictures.nextToken);
  ....
```

I find my first page is the same as my second page.
How to initialize the nextToken, when I list the first page?
I do not know the nextToken at first.

Comment: Are you getting an error with the current code?

Answer (score 0):

For the first page your `nextToken` must be `null` as described [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-graphql/graphql-pagination/q/platform/js/).

There's nothing else wrong, try this:

```
const [nextToken, setNextToken] = useState("");

const fetchData = async (nToken = nextToken, size = perPage) => {
    try {
        const pictureData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listPictures,
            {
                limit: size,
                nextToken: nToken ? nToken : null
            }));
        setNextToken(pictureData.data.listPictures.nextToken);
...
```